# Dynamically add or remove a member variable of a class

Tags: json, callout, httprequest

I have a JSON request class:

```
public with sharing class RequestANA {
    public Notice notice = new Notice ();
    public class Notice {
        public String idExternal;
        public String name;
        public String surname;
        public String phone;
        public String addressNumber;
        ....;
    }
    public RequestANA(Case caseToSend) {
        this.notice.idExternal = caseToSend.CaseNumber;
        this.notice.name = caseToSend.Account.FirstName;
        this.notice.surname = caseToSend.Account.LastName;
        this.notice.phone = caseToSend.ContactPhone;
        if(caseToSend.Number_Address__c != null) {
            this.avviso.addressNumber=  String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(caseToSend.Number_Address__c));
        }
    }
}
```

Now if `caseToSend.Number_Address__c` is `null`, in the request I don't want the `addressNumber` key. I don't want it to just be equal to `null` but I want in such a way that it doesn't exist at all in the JSON request.

How can I do it?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why is it important for you to avoid having null values? Are you trying to serialize this to be sent via a callout, or are you receiving this data from a callout? Apex doesn't let you modify class definitions dynamically like that (as opposed to, say, Javascript). Depending on what precisely you're trying to do, using a `Map<String, Object>` instead of a class may work.

Comment: I am serialzing it. It is a requirement of the client.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand your question completely, are you serializing an instance of this class, and do not want the Number_Address__c in the JSON?

If so, look at [serialize(objectToSerialize, suppressApexObjectNulls)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

Comment: I would like only that particular field to not exist, not all the fields that are empty. Is it possible?

Comment: If you only want that one field to not be included, then serialize the object, and the do a string replace to remove it:
`
    Notice n;
    ...
    string json = serialize(n);
    json = json.replace('"addressNumber": null,', '');
`

Comment: Trying to get code block formatting for my previous statement above

`Notice n;  `
`...  `  
`String json = serialize(n);`  
`json = json.replace('"addressNumber": null,', '');`

Answer (score 1):

Create a below Function -->

```
 public String generateRequest(object requestObj, Boolean suppressNull) {
    return System.JSON.serializePretty(requestObj, suppressNull);
  }

Notice notice = new Notice ();
//
// Prefill Your notice DTO
//
// requestBody json contain eliminated null value, blank value are not eliminated
String requestBody = generateRequest(notice,true);
```